# How to fix structured data errors in Google Webmaster Tools – missing author, entry title and updated

Tags: php, wordpress, google-search-console, structured-data

Google Webmaster Tools is reporting a bunch of structured data errors – `Missing: author`, `Missing: entry-title` and `Missing: updated`. Looking at other threads about this issue, it is suggested that I should add certain classes to `the_author`, `the_title` and `the_time`. However, I can't find `the_author` or `the_time` in any of the .php files in my theme folder. I found `the_title` in content.php, but it already had the class entry-title.
I'm using WordPress CMS with a custom theme based on Twenty Thirteen, in case it might be theme-related.

Any idea how to fix this?